# In the episode "Cold Blood", how can the Doctor remember Rory?

Tags: doctor-who

When Rory dies and is consumed by the crack in the universe, he is removed from existence and Amy cannot remember him. But the Doctor can.

Why did the Doctor not forget Rory as well?

Comment: It's a bunch of wibbly-wobbly timey-wimey... stuff.

Comment: Because the Doctor is a Time Lord. Time Lords are good at those things.

Comment: Maybe, and that's a big maybe, the Doctor can remember him, because he himself is/was/has been/will be in the crack. Time is definitely messed up in the crack, considering what causes the crack and what ultimately seals it.

Comment: Time travelers who have experienced the time vortex experience time differently than non-time travelers are outsiders to normal timelines. Amy was eventually able to remember Rory.

Comment: To go with what others have said, consider the fate of the soldiers and angels in [Time of the Angels](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Time_of_Angels) -- Amy, the Doctor and River were all aware of their vanishing, due to being 'complicated space-time events' themselves, due to traveling in time.  Why can Amy remember them, but not Rory, however, is a good question -- it may just be a matter of Degree at this point, as the memory limit is clearly not insurmountable as is shown at the end of [The Pandorica Opens](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Alliance_%28The_Pandorica_Opens%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was addressed in the dialogue. Apparently the rule is that time travelers can normally remember people swallowed by the cracks (as the Doctor had explained when she still remembered the clerics who she talked to in "Flesh and Stone" even after they were swallowed), *except* if the person being erased would change the time traveler's own history (I guess in some 'sufficiently significant' way, since those clerics were a minor part of Amy's history before being swallowed, just as Rory was a minor part of the Doctor's history). From the [transcript of Cold Blood](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/31-9.htm):

> AMY: Doctor, we can't just leave him there.
>
> DOCTOR: Keep him in your mind. Don't forget him. If you forget him, you'll lose him forever.
>
> AMY: When we were on the Byzantium, I still remembered the Clerics because I am a time traveller now, you said.
>
> DOCTOR: They weren't part of your world. This is different. This is your own history changing.

And here was the earlier dialogue [from Flesh and Stone](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/31-5.htm):

> AMY: Then why do I remember it at all? Those guys on the ship didn't remember each other.
>
> DOCTOR: You're a time traveller now. Amy. It changes the way you see the universe, forever. Good, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The Doctor is a Time Lord, raised on Gallifrey, a planet with an opening into the vortex of space/time on it (Sound of Drums).  This long interaction with the species of that planet triggered an evolutionary adaptation (Demon's Run) which allows Time Lords to see possible pasts and futures. (Numerous references, first explicit I believe in Fires of Pompeii).

Amy grew up with a crack in space-time in her wall.  While nowhere near as evolved as any infant Time Lord is at birth, this life long proximity apparently had an impact on her development (Time of Angels, Big Bang, Wedding of River Song) which gives her the ability to remember things that happened but then un-happened because of a temporal change.  This ability is less powerful than the Doctor's and much more significant impacts on her own timeline (the loss of 1 of her 2 child hood best friends) are harder to retain (Time of Angels, Wedding of River Song) but she can do it with a strong enough reminder (Pandorica, Big Bang).

*Speculative Aside - this enhanced ability may have contributed to the evolutionary change triggered in Melody which caused her genetic material to closely resemble Time Lord DNA (Demon's Run) which occurred as a result of her having been conceived while the TARDIS was in-flight (Demon's Run)